# populating RecyclerView from AsyncTask fails and results in empty Screen

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Trying to populate data to a `RecyclerView` from cloud, though I get output in Main Thread, it takes time, so decided to add an `AsyncTask` to load items with ease and also to insert a `ProgressDialog`, however now it seems like code has no effect, getting an empty screen.

But the `AsyncTask` is getting executed, as I am able to log items in the logcat, no idea why I don't get a RecyclerView. Here is the code I use and looking for help:

```
public class BigBoard extends ActionBarActivity {

private List<Person> persons;
private RecyclerView rv;
private RVAdapter adapter;
private String a,b;
private ProgressDialog pr;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Parse.initialize(this, "app-id", "client-key");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_big_board);

    Loader abc = new Loader();
    abc.execute();
    adapter = new RVAdapter(persons);
    rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);



}



private class Loader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pr = new ProgressDialog(BigBoard.this);
        pr.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pr.setIndeterminate(true);
        pr.setCancelable(false);
        pr.setMessage("Loading Board");
        pr.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        initializeData();

        initializeAdapter();


        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pr.dismiss();

    }

    private void initializeData(){
        persons = new ArrayList<>();


        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("BigBoard");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> credentialList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for(int i=0;i<credentialList.size();i++)
                    {
                        a=credentialList.get(i).getString("Location");
                        b=credentialList.get(i).getString("Feed");
                        persons.add(new Person(a,b));



                        Log.d("OUT", "So the Val::------> " +a +b);


                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    private void initializeAdapter(){

        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Show us your adapter class. It's not clear what data it's reading from.Do you know that the persons ArrayList is actually being read by the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

place the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` or `rv.setAdapter(adapter);`
to onPostExecute..
since onOPostExecute works on UI Thread.

Edit :
create a function inside the Adapter

```
public void updatePersons(List<Person> persons) {
    this.persons = persons;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

after filling the list in onPostExecute call this function the List.

Comment: Tried both, no effect :/

Comment: the bug is definitely in `doInBackground()` I guess, as the `ProgressDialog` was working flawless before adding code to  `doInBackground()`